# Flex mx.controls.TextInput initial width

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, textinput

Flex's `mx.controls.TextInput` default width is documented as:

> The size of the text with a default minimum size of 22 pixels high and
>   160 pixels wide

Is there a way to change the initial width? 160 pixels is too wide for my application. If I specify an absolute width (`width="100"`), then it doesn't scale as parent container width changes. If I specify `width="100%"`, it scales to the parent container, but still defaults to 160. There is `measuredWidth`, but it gets set by `measure()`. I could extend `TextInput` and override `measure()`, but I'd rather just use `TextInput` as is.

I'm using Flex 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Set stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE and minWidth should work because interface elements won't scale so your text field will keep its width.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use constraint-based parameters such as left & right, instead of x and width. For example:

```
<mx:TextInput left="5" right="5" />
```